# How to retrieve properties only once from database in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, memoization

I have some relationships in my database that I describe like that:

```
@property
def translations(self):
    """
    :return: QuerySet
    """
    if not hasattr(self, '_translations'):
        self._translations = ClientTranslation.objects.filter(base=self)
    return self._translations
```

The idea behind the `hasattr()` and `self._translation` is to have the db only hit one time, while the second time the stored property is returned.

However, after reading, the docs, I'm not sure if the code is doing that - as queries are only hitting the db when the values are really needed - which comes after my code.

How would a correct approach look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, DB is hit the first time someone needs the value. But as you pointed out, you save the query, not the results.  Wrap the query with `list(...)` to save the results.

By the way, you can use the `cached_property` decorator to make it more elegant. It is not a built-in, though.  It can be found [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Cached_Properties).  You end up with:

```
@cached_property
def translations(self):
    return list(ClientTranslation.objects.filter(base=self))
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, but I do only save the query, not the result, right? (I'll use that decorator, but would like to know).

Comment: btw: I see, django comes with battery included: `from django.utils.functional import cached_property` does the trick alike.